# Ubuntu Server install on RAID0

Tags: server, 20.04, raid

Trying to setup RAID0 on a server 20.04. I have 2 new NVME drives and the ubuntu installer is only showing 1 drive as multipath. If I use shell and run lsblk then I see both drives. The desktop installer sees both drives no issue. Is there a way to get the server install to see both drives? I have tried following these steps with no luck as well https://saelzler.com/tech/disable-multipath-for-identical-nvme-drives-on-ubuntu-server/

Secondly, if I create the partitions and RAID0 array manually in shell, the ubuntu server installer crashes when I go through all the steps. If I format both drives so there are no partitions, and I create the RAID array using the installer, it still crashes.

Comment: Hello. Following what steps?

Comment: SOrry about the slow response. These steps: https://saelzler.com/tech/disable-multipath-for-identical-nvme-drives-on-ubuntu-server/  I get these to work, but why is ubuntu server always seeing these as multipath?